# Why can I not execute my javascript function by using an event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, button, event-listener

Javascript

```
const btn0 = document.querySelector('.btn0');
btn0.addEventListener('click', function() {
    showNum(0);
})

function showNum(value)
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="0" name="btn0" id="btn0"  />
```

I have included the relevant code above.  The showNum function is fully implemented and working, I just didn't include it because it was irrelevant.

I need to call the showNum function with an event listener but can't figure out why my code is not working.  When debugging I can see that addBtn is null and no matter what I try it stays that way.  I have been struggling with this for an hour and am frustrated at how simple it should be.

I have tried different ways of initializing addBtn such as using getElementByName, but when debugging through the program btn0 is always null.

Comment: What's this `addBtn` you refer to? **When** do you add the event listener? Did you try accessing it by ID?

Answer (score 1):

`btn0` is not a `class` instead it is an `id` so you have to use `#` in place of `.` in

```
const btn0= document.querySelector('#btn0');
```

```js
const btn0 = document.querySelector('#btn0');   // CHANGE
btn0.addEventListener('click', function() {
  showNum(0);
})

function showNum(value) {
  console.log('Inside showNum functon with value: ', value);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="0" name="btn0" id="btn0" />
```

You can also find button using attribute also as:

```
document.querySelector('[name="btn0"]');
```

```js
const btn0 = document.querySelector('[name="btn0"]'); // CHANGE
btn0.addEventListener('click', function() {
  showNum(0);
})

function showNum(value) {
  console.log('Inside showNum functon with value: ', value);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="0" name="btn0" id="btn0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You a are using querySelector to select the button element with the class name .btn0  However, in the HTML ,  **the button element has an ID of btn0, not a class name.**

To select an element by ID, you should use the getElementById method instead of querySelector. Try changing your code to the following:

```
const btn0 = document.getElementById('btn0');
btn0.addEventListener('click', function() {
    showNum(0);
});
```